# loading image though socket in bytestring takes forever in python

Tags: python, image, sockets

I am wondering how i can send an image through a python socket.

I have already tried it with pickle and sending the byte string piece by piece. However that takes forever.

Here is what I have tried.

my server code:

```py
import socket
from PIL import Image
import pickle

host=""
port=80
server=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(("", port))
server.listen()
path=("path")
image=Image.open(path)

def acc():
    while True:
        conn, addr=server.accept()
        print("connected to %s" %(conn))
        conn.send(pickle.dumps(image))

acc()
```

my client code:

```py
import socket
import pickle
host="192.168.1.11"
port=80
c=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
c.connect((host, port))

while True:
    while True:
        data=[]
        packet=c.recv(100000)
        if not packet: break
        data.append(packet)
    data_arr=b"".join(data)
    print(pickle.loads(data_arr))
```

If the answer is not with pickle or PIL it is fine. I just need a way how this works. I'm looking forward for answers!

Comment: Just a sec... I did it yesturday

Comment: Simply, you just wait infinitely in your client for the image and in your server you don't close the socket and continue to server other clients.

Comment: Yeah basicly, just dont know how to convert it with htonl  and convert it to BytesIO but i think i will find out

Answer (score 1):

```
import socket, time

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(("10.0.0.9", 2000))
server.listen()

def acc(image_Path):
    with open(image_Path, "rb") as image:
        data = image.read() # Read the bytes from the path
        image.close()

    while True:
        conn, addr = server.accept()
        print("connected to %s" %(conn))

        conn.sendall(data) # Send the bytes

acc("The path of the image to transform")
```

```
import socket
import pickle
host = "10.0.0.9"
port = 2000
c = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
c.connect((host, port))

while True:
    data = c.recv(100000000) # We don't know the size of the image, so 100000000 just in case


    with open("The path of the location of the image that recived", "wb") as newImage:
        newImage.write(data) # Write the bytes in new path to create the image
        newImage.close()


    print("Got the image")
```

Comment: You don't need `image.close()` inside a `with` statement - it's automagical ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is neither **PIL** nor **Pickle**!

- If you have a 31kB JPEG of a 1920x1080 image and you open it with **PIL**, it will get JPEG-decompressed and expanded out into a 1920x1080x3 RGB image in memory - which will require a minimum of 6,220,800 bytes, i.e. you have increased its size by 200 times. Moral of the story is to send the (compressed) JPEG itself.
- If you then pickle that 6MB monster, it will a) take longer and b) get bigger and it is entirely unnecessary because you can send binary data down a socket anyway.

---

The easiest way is to:

- simply `read()` the JPEG/PNG file using Python `read()` rather than **PIL** `Image.read()`
- do not pickle it
- send a 4-byte header in network order (see `htonl()`) with the image size before your image and, on the receiving end, read 4 bytes and unpack them, then read the correct number of bytes in the image
- put the received bytes into a `BytesIO` structure and then use **PIL** `Image.open(BYTESIO_THING)`

Comment: okay, understandable. Can you code my example out with your strategy because i have no idea how the code will look like.

Comment: You can heavily base it on @זיו שיאון code. Just get the length of the image after you have read it with `nBytes = len(data)` and convert that with `htonl()` and send it before the `conn.sendall()` In the client, read 4 bytes and convert it back to an integer before you get the image itself and then read exactly that many bytes.